# Unable to add a class attribute to the label generated by a radio button input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have the following configuration:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb
config.item_wrapper_tag = :div
config.item_wrapper_class = 'form-check'

# config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb

config.wrappers :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly
  b.use :label, class: 'control-label'
  b.use :input, class: 'form-check-input'
  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
  b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
end
```

When I create a radio button input I get this -

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons required profile_sex">
  <label class="control-label radio_buttons required">
    <abbr title="required">*</abbr> 
    Gender
  </label>
  <div class="radio form-check">
    <label for="profile_sex_male">
      <input class="form-check-input radio_buttons required" value="Male" name="profile[sex]" id="profile_sex_male" type="radio">
      Male          
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio form-check">
    <label for="profile_sex_female">
      <input class="form-check-input radio_buttons required" value="Female" name="profile[sex]" id="profile_sex_female" type="radio">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2 , to improve the layout and positioning of radio buttons one is supposed to have radio buttons to have the following structure:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
    Male
  </label>
</div>
```

Refer [Bootstrap#forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios/)

Observe the class attribute attached to the label - `form-check-label`. How do I add this html class to a label generated by a radio button collection in `simple_forms` ?

Comment: According to this comment https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1516 there is a custom initlaizer already in gem ( called simple_form_bootstrap_4.rb). If you haven’t tried it then it’d probably be better than writing your own.

Comment: I haven't worked with initializers, but have you tried setting `label_html` on input instead?